# Recursive function cannot return a boolean

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, boolean

I want to write Python function that returns true a string s is a palindrome, that is, it is equal to its reverse. For example 'racecar' and 'abba' are palindromes. So far this is my unsuccessful attempt.

```
 def ispalindrome(s):
    if len(s) == 1:
        return s
    else:
        reverse = s[-1] + ispalindrome(s[:-1])
```

I have no problem when I tell my function to return the reverse, however, I am confused to how should I make the comparison in order to return a bool.

```
def ispalindrome(s):
    if len(s) == 1:
        return s
    else:
        reverse = s[-1] + ispalindrome(s[:-1])
        return a == reverse
```

using the function above creates the following error

```
>>>ispalindrome('racecar')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    ispalindrome('racecar')
  File "/Users/Nadir/Desktop/Untitled.py", line 24, in ispalindrome
    reverse = s[-1] + ispalindrome(s[:-1])
  File "/Users/Nadir/Desktop/Untitled.py", line 24, in ispalindrome
    reverse = s[-1] + ispalindrome(s[:-1])
  File "/Users/Nadir/Desktop/Untitled.py", line 24, in ispalindrome
    reverse = s[-1] + ispalindrome(s[:-1])
  File "/Users/Nadir/Desktop/Untitled.py", line 24, in ispalindrome
    reverse = s[-1] + ispalindrome(s[:-1])
  File "/Users/Nadir/Desktop/Untitled.py", line 24, in ispalindrome
    reverse = s[-1] + ispalindrome(s[:-1])
TypeError: Can't convert 'bool' object to str implicitly
```

Now I fully understand why the error above is produced. It is because some of the recursive functions return a bool and attempt to add it to a string; but what I can't do is how to avoid this error.

Comment: Why not just test the first and last characters, and chop them off before recursing?

Comment: I could, but I am looking for a way where i can use the 'reverse' that is produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better recursive test for a palindrome may be just to ensure the end characters are identical then that the inner characters are also a palindrome, with the termination condition of ending up with a zero- or one-character string (which is, be definition, a palindrome):

```
def isPalindrome(s):
    if len(s) < 2:
        return True
    if s[0] != s[-1]:
        return False
    return isPalindrome(s[1:-1])

print isPalindrome("racecar")
```

It's rather difficult trying to create an elegant recursive solution to this problem when you can only mess about with the string at *one* end, since you'll need to pass down the original string for comparison, the remains of string you're currently reversing, and the reversed string to date, something like:

```
def isPalindrome(orig, reduced, reversed):
    if reduced == "":
        return orig == reversed
    return isPalindrome(orig, reduced[1:], reduced[0] + reversed)

print isPalindrome("racecar", "racecar", "")
```

---

Of course, the whole idea of doing this recursively is flawed, for anything other than education (since education is probably your goal here, it's okay as an example).

But keep in mind that the best use cases for recursion are where you can dispose of a large chunk of the "solution space" with each recursive call (witness the binary search which can dispose of half the remaining space each time).

A large enough string for a recursive palindrome function will have the same effect as the following function, the *classic* case of poor algorithm selection in the recursive arena:

```
def add(unsigned a, unsigned b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    return add(a+1, b-1)
```

in that you'll probably run out of stack space long before you get an answer :-)